# I can't install VNC

Tags: software-installation, vnc

Recently I have been trying to install VNC on my raspberry pi 3 but it won't work. It may be because I used the incorrect name for the file. I have used: sudo apt-get install VNC,sudo apt-get install VNC connect, etc. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should learn to use the tools.

`apt-cache search name` will find all packages mentioning name.

```
apt-cache search vnc
```

Will show packages which mention VNC, and you then use `apt-cache showpkg` to explore e.g. `apt-cache showpkg tightvncserver`

There is already a VNC package installed by default, although IMO it is not the most flexible.

You will find hundreds of posts on this site tagged [vnc]